# When to use possessive pronouns vs. dative pronoun + definite article

Tags: grammar, usage, dative, possessive

German uses a reflexive dative pronoun and a regular definite article in many places where English would use a possessive pronoun. For example:

> I broke my leg.
>   **Ich habe mir das Bein gebrochen.**
>
> I wash my hands. 
>   **Ich wasche mir die Hände.**

Is this as normalized in spoken German as in written? Would you *ever* say *Ich habe meine Hände gewaschen* or *Ich habe mein Bein gebrochen?*

I’m wondering how frequently the form with the dative pronoun has to be used.  Should I say *Das Baby hat mir den Finger gebissen* or *Das Baby hat meinen Finger gebissen?*  Likewise, *Ich kitzele seine Füße (z.B. die Füße des Babys)* or *Ich kitzele ihm die Füße?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

“Ich habe meine Hände gewaschen” sounds unusual, but not wrong. Regarding the broken leg, I can imagine saying something like “Ich hab’s Bein gebrochen” (= *habe das*), but “Ich habe mein Bein gebrochen” is too active, as if it had been intentional.

“Das Baby hat mir den Finger gebissen” is wrong; it should be “Das Baby hat mir *in* den Finger gebissen”. Similarly, “Ich habe mir *auf* die Zunge gebissen”. “Das Baby hat meinen Finger gebissen” is again unusual.

For *kitzeln*, both of your examples are OK (but it is normally “kitzle” instead of “kitzele”).

Comment: For kitzeln you usually say "Ich kitzele das Baby *an den* Füßen".

Comment: @chirlu, What if someone else did it?  Would you say "Ich habe dein Bein gebrochen" or "Ich habe dir das Bein gebrochen"?

Comment: It’s normally “Ich habe dir das Bein gebrochen” even here.